# Attempting to write a document for a peer review publication. Having trouble making a template work

Tags: packages

I am wanting to write a Latex document for peer review publication. I have found a template at http://msp.org/gt/macros/gtpartdoc.pdf

But when I paste this into Latex I get the error code:

```
! Latex Error : File 'gtpart.cls' not found.
```

The following is what I am pasting into Latex:

```
\documentclass{gtpart}



\usepackage{pinlabel}
%%% Start of metadata
\title[An airy sample]{An airy sample\\for demonstration purposes}
%  First author
%
\author[J\,R Smith]{James R Smith}
\givenname{James R}
\surname{Smith}
\address{Department of Mathematics\\
The University of the Air\\\newline
27 However Road\\Coalsport CL65 7UL\\UK}
\email{jrs@maths.air.ac.uk}
\urladdr{http://www.maths.air.ac.uk/~jrs}
%  Second author
%
\author[W von Jones]{William von Jones}
\givenname{William}
\surname{von Jones}
\address{Department of Mathematics\\
The University of Fire\\\newline
59 Wherever Road\\Dinkington DK25 6AR\\UK}
\email{w.jones@maths.fire.ac.uk}
\urladdr{}
%
%  Add a similar block for other authors
%
\keyword{air}
\keyword{fire}
\keyword{five elements}
\keyword{sample}
Mathematical Sciences Publishers: documentation
Using gtpart.cls: LATEX instructions for authors 3
\subject{primary}{msc2000}{58M56}
\subject{primary}{msc2000}{59Q23}
\subject{secondary}{msc2000}{22X99}
\subject{secondary}{msc2000}{21Y73}
\subject{secondary}{msc2000}{18Q18}
\arxivreference{math.AW/0611679}
\arxivpassword{5spud}
%  Leave the following items blank
%
\volumenumber{}
\issuenumber{}
\publicationyear{}
\papernumber{}
\startpage{}
\endpage{}
\doi{}
\MR{}
\Zbl{}
\received{}
\revised{}
\accepted{}
\published{}
\publishedonline{}
\proposed{}
\seconded{}
\corresponding{}
\editor{}
\version{}
%%% End of metadata
%
%%% Start of user-defined macros %%%
%
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{zlem}{Zorn’s Lemma}
%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
%
%
Mathematical Sciences Publishers: documentation
4 Colin Rourke
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\makeop{Homo}
\newcommand{\bbl}{\mathbb{L}}
%%% End of user-defined macros %%%
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
This is a short abstract inserted just for demonstration purposes.
You can use mathematical statements eg $\Homo(G)\iso\Gamma$ but
NOT environments inside the abstract.  If you really must use an
environment (eg an itemized list) then enclose it in braces.
\end{abstract}
\begin{asciiabstract}
This is a short abstract inserted just for demonstration purposes.
You can use mathematical statements eg Homo(G) is isomorphic to
Gamma but NOT environments inside the abstract.  If you really
must use an environment (eg an itemized list) then enclose it in
braces.
\end{asciiabstract}
\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   Start of main body of article

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many journal classes are not released to CTAN, thus is not a part of your LaTeX installation. You will probably have to download the class from somewhere. Afterwards, just place the `.cls` file in the same folder as your article.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where do you paste the code into? A specific LaTeX editor? Apparently you don't have the `gtpart.cls` installed

Comment: I've found some strange position of `gtpart.cls` on my TL 2015 distribution: `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pinlabel/src/gtpart.cls`. I don't know whether this is the same class then

Comment: Thank you for your speedy replies! I am using a mac and the application is called TexShop. How do I go about obtaining gtpart.cls?

Comment: There are some parts of the document which misses `%`, the lines with `Mathematical Sciences` and following ones --> this can't be typeset in the preamble and is presumably not meant to be typeset at all

Comment: I have added a '%' at the begging of these lines but it still comes up with an error about gtpart.cls. I still don't know how to solve this error.

Comment: How could you have found a template at a URI that ends in `.pdf`? A template is usually in the form of a "class" file, which ends in `.cls`. The presence (or lack thereof) of a PDF on your system will not help you use a specific class. You should reread daleif's earlier comment and follow his advice.

Comment: Hi Jon. The template is in the URL. Unfortunately I do not understand the advice. I'm lost to how I find this gtpart.cls, and I also don't know what to do once I have downloaded it. I hope you can help!

Comment: Do I have to do something with this? http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pinlabel/src/gtpart.cls

Comment: In a `.tex` file, the line that goes `\documentclass{gtpart}` is telling LaTeX that you want to use a class file by the name `gtpart.cls`. I cannot understand how the "template is in the URL", since the URL is just pointing to a PDF that explains how to use the so-called template.  As @ChristianHupfer said, the `.cls` might already be on your system, but is located in a place where LaTeX can't find it. So try putting that `.cls` in your working folder and running the file you posted again.

Comment: But comment out the lines Christian said: they look like the result of a careless cut and paste or something.

Comment: I have done a search on my computer and it has found no matches for 'gtpart.cls' What kind of document should this 'gtpart.cls' be? - I am a complete newbie to all this, so please treat me as one!

Comment: Use the one you linked to in a previous comment.

Comment: How do I 'use' the link?

Comment: Download the file and save it in your working directory (i.e., where your `.tex` file is).

Comment: These must sound like really silly questions... but how do I 'download' tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pinlabel/src/gtpart.cls ? For me it is just a webpage.

Comment: No it is actually a file, just like a webpage that ends in `.html` is a file (or one ending `.pdf` would be a file). Can't you do something like "save as..."? Save it as `gtpart.cls` in the folder where you have the corresponding `.tex` file.  Otherwise, copy and paste the whole thing into a file with the name `gtpart.cls`.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for your help and patience!

Comment: The linked pdf requires some basics to be known, you can learn these basics in [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gtpart.cls` is located in a rather unhelpful place in TeX Live 2015. (This should therefore apply to MacTeX users, I think.) This should be brought to the attention of the developers if they mean it to be included in TeX Live.

The class (`.cls`) file can be acquired from [CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pinlabel/src/gtpart.cls). Or, from your working directory. you can do something like

```sh
cp $(locate gtpart.cls) .
```

which should copy the file into the directory your terminal is currently visiting. If you plan on using this file more than once, you might consider moving it somewhere more appropriate.

Once you have the file, run your example file from above (I include it here, with some lines taken out, which I think are the result of a careless cut-and-paste from the PDF that is linked to in the question.)

```
\documentclass{gtpart}

\usepackage{pinlabel}
%%% Start of metadata
\title[An airy sample]{An airy sample\\for demonstration purposes}
%  First author
%
\author[J\,R Smith]{James R Smith}
\givenname{James R}
\surname{Smith}
\address{Department of Mathematics\\
The University of the Air\\\newline
27 However Road\\Coalsport CL65 7UL\\UK}
\email{jrs@maths.air.ac.uk}
\urladdr{http://www.maths.air.ac.uk/~jrs}
%  Second author
%
\author[W von Jones]{William von Jones}
\givenname{William}
\surname{von Jones}
\address{Department of Mathematics\\
The University of Fire\\\newline
59 Wherever Road\\Dinkington DK25 6AR\\UK}
\email{w.jones@maths.fire.ac.uk}
\urladdr{}
%
%  Add a similar block for other authors
%
\keyword{air}
\keyword{fire}
\keyword{five elements}
\keyword{sample}

\subject{primary}{msc2000}{58M56}
\subject{primary}{msc2000}{59Q23}
\subject{secondary}{msc2000}{22X99}
\subject{secondary}{msc2000}{21Y73}
\subject{secondary}{msc2000}{18Q18}
\arxivreference{math.AW/0611679}
\arxivpassword{5spud}
%  Leave the following items blank
%
\volumenumber{}
\issuenumber{}
\publicationyear{}
\papernumber{}
\startpage{}
\endpage{}
\doi{}
\MR{}
\Zbl{}
\received{}
\revised{}
\accepted{}
\published{}
\publishedonline{}
\proposed{}
\seconded{}
\corresponding{}
\editor{}
\version{}
%%% End of metadata
%
%%% Start of user-defined macros %%%
%
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{zlem}{Zorn’s Lemma}
%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
%
%

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\makeop{Homo}
\newcommand{\bbl}{\mathbb{L}}
%%% End of user-defined macros %%%
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
This is a short abstract inserted just for demonstration purposes.
% You can use mathematical statements eg $\Homo(G)\iso\Gamma$ but <-- this line seems wrong, so I changed it. It raises an error if left in
 You can use mathematical statements eg $\Homo(G) is isomorphic to \Gamma$ but
NOT environments inside the abstract.  If you really must use an
environment (eg an itemized list) then enclose it in braces.
\end{abstract}
\begin{asciiabstract}
This is a short abstract inserted just for demonstration purposes.
You can use mathematical statements eg Homo(G) is isomorphic to
Gamma but NOT environments inside the abstract.  If you really
must use an environment (eg an itemized list) then enclose it in
braces.
\end{asciiabstract}
\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Comment: The file `gtpart.cls` is in the documentation tree for the `pinlabel` package, but I believe it shouldn't be there, as it has no licensing information.

Comment: @egreg -- Indeed. No licensing information, `kpsewhich` can't find it. I'd say there's a few problems....